# How to draw a diagram defining a map as the composition of two other maps?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

I would like to know what is the most common way of drawing a diagram to define a certain map $h: X  \to Z$ as the composition of some two mappings: $f : X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say

> $h$ is defined so that following diagram commutes:
>
> [image]
> <sub>(source: [presheaf.com](http://presheaf.com/cache/d66312l2v3hk1z734l30w3q1h5nw1t.png))</sub>

which for this simple diagram is precisely the same as saying that $h=gf$.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is the following:

[image]
<sub>(source: [presheaf.com](http://presheaf.com/cache/d3d221p5j4z4v6w74d1866v2l6s3d9.png))</sub>